# How can you get a user's mysite image url based on a list's AuthorId?

Tags: 2013, javascript, my-site, rest

I have a list that I am using SharePoint 2013's rest API to grab info from.

I would like to display an image of the user who created the list.

This [site](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html) shows how to get a user's image url based on their username:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'
```

Using this rest api:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list_title>')/items
```

The only information I can find about the user who created the item in the list is the `AuthorId`

**How can you get a user's MySite info based on the AuthorId of a user?**

Note:

Microsoft redirects you to the correct user's MySite page if you use this link:

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=<AuthorId>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following call, you can get the Login Name of the user from the AuthorID:

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/GetUserById(<AuthorID>)/LoginName
```

And then by using the Login Name, you can get the Picture Url with the following call:

```
http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='<LoginName>'&$select=PictureUrl
```

Comment: Awesome!  One issue: Since we use Claims auth I get this for the login name: i:0#.w|<domain>\<username>.  When I remove i:0#.w| and use your second query it works like a charm, otherwise I get an error.  Should I just use a string replace to remove that part or is there a better query?

Comment: In the first query, you can use the `Email` property to get only the part you want:
`http://siteurl/_api/web/GetUserById(<AuthorID>)/Email`

Comment: @Vardhaman Deshpande My question is not directly related but somehow relevant. To get the pictureURL, we need to know the MYSITEURL, how do i find out the mysite URl for a user?(other than the constructing the URL from the email which I am aware of) is there an API call which retrieves that info?

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan you can use the `PersonalUrl` or `UserUrl` properties to get the My Site Urls.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande Yes indeed, but to get this info i have to know the server URL right? In sharepoint online/office 365 what is that? https://<tenantName>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getPropertiesFor('i%3A0%23.f%7Cmembership%7Cadmin%40tenantname.com')

is this correct? or do i need to use a different server URL here?